# MiniColors picker not updating color variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to implement [MiniColors](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/).  MiniColors works OK, but I can't get the value of variable colorSet to update when MiniColors is changed.  I have an txt input #colour with shows the default value, but that value is not updating...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#picker').minicolors({
            opacity: false,
            defaultValue: '#2083fd',
            control: 'hue',
            textfield: false,
            change: function(hex, opacity) {
                $('#picker').val(hex); 
             }
        });

        var colourSet = $('#picker').val();
        $('#colour').val(colourSet);
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `colourSet` to update every time the color is changed, the assignment needs to go inside the `change` event function. Right now you have it setting `colourSet` once, after the minicolor is initiated. I think you want something like the code below. Also, you can probably get rid of the variable and set the `#colour` element directly, if desired.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colourSet;

    $('#picker').minicolors({
        opacity: false,
        defaultValue: '#2083fd',
        control: 'hue',
        textfield: false,
        change: function(hex, opacity) {
            $('#picker').val(hex);
            colourSet = hex;
            $('#colour').val(colourSet);
         }
    });
```